# Visual Studio 2010 - After build performance issue (application start takes ages)

Tags: .net, performance, visual-studio-2010, obfuscation

### Prologue

Two days ago I installed a few obfuscators. The setup process of Eazfuscator took a while and said it was optimizing and [something else]. This seemed a bit weird to me, so I remembered this step.

Because Eazfuscator didn't work for me I decided to uninstall it. I **did** try the program, by dragging my solution to the Eazfuscator-window.

Anyway, after installing a few obfuscators and try-outs I decided not to use any of them.

### So, while not using ANY obfuscators...

If I now compile my WPF Application (.NET 4.0 Client Profile) no build errors or whatsoever. When building is done, the start-up of the Application takes ages! Like 23 seconds while it was 2 or 3 before...

This morning I tried my solution on another VS2010 installation (another computer) and it is as fast as it was before!!

**What I did so far**

- In the meanwhile I reinstalled the complete .NET 4 Framework (full and client) but no success
- Application is still readable via ILDASM
- Code analyzers/optimizers say nothing weird

So, **Any hints** where to look for settings (or so) are highly appreciated!

### Edit : Solution

Thanks to the suggestion of Mr Dissapointment I got my VS2010 working like it should! Use `devenv /resetsettings` to fix Visual Studio issues that cannot be explained...?

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think what you have tried is looking too far down the line: I think it is likely that one or more of the programs have integrated, in some sense (even loosely) with the Visual Studio application itself - you might want to concentrate your efforts there.

Comment: The Tools menu does not show anything concerning obfuscators (except dotfuscator). Any other places to look for?

Comment: Well, perhaps as a last resort if nobody provides any working help for you, you might consider restoring VS back to its "factory state" - which might help - by using the following command: `devenv /resetsettings`

Comment: Aah! Many thanks! I definitely will give that a try. I just want to know where it went wrong, should be something configurable I assume.

Comment: Any IL-rewriters in play here? code-contracts? postsharp (aka sharpcrafters)?

Comment: Is it the same behaviour if you start your application from within Visual Studio and stand-alone? Are you using the Visual Studio Hosting process, if so, does it change if you disable it?

Comment: @MarcGravell No, just a normal build.

Comment: @Dominik Yes, same behaviour if I run the via F5 and manually start the exe.

Comment: @321X Out of curiosity, if you take the build from the "broken" machine and take it to the clean one, is the startup still taking that long?

Comment: @Dominik The compiled source takes as long. The copied solution is working like it should

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment If you post your suggestion about resetsettings, I can accept it as an answer, because it helped solving my problem! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a hunch, but I think what you have tried is looking too far down the line: I think it is likely that one or more of the programs have integrated, in some sense (even loosely) with the Visual Studio application itself - you might want to concentrate your efforts there.

Perhaps as a last resort, if nobody provides any other working help for you, you might consider restoring VS back to its "factory state" - which might help - by using the following command:

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

<sub>Posting from solution made in comments for the sake of data integrity</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Now other people also know this was a helpful solution!